# OnNewIntent through external class

Tags: android, nfc

I am developing an application for NFC.
On the tags, we have an application record, what is starting our application, and a text record, what has an id. When my app is reading the textrecord, send a request through the net to our server, get the response, and do things, like show buttons, doesn't matter.

When i started to learn android, i learned, there is a good thing to use a general engine, what has a lot of tool for myself, so when i need a new app, i can reuse my engine functions.

So, i've created this GameEngine class as a separated project.
I tried it without TAG_DISCOVERED filter, also tried when i've give not the text/plain mime type, but my application.

```
package GameEngine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public abstract class GameEngine extends Activity {
private final String TAG = "DH GAME ENGINE";

     /**************************************************
         * Here are the override methods
     */
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Engine constructor");
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         init();
     }

    public abstract void init();
    //MORE overrides here...
}
```

In my app, i have the init function. Here i set up the layout, set some flags.
In the onNewIntent method, i have this piece of code:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Log.d(TAG, "A tag was scanned!");
    GEPhone.vibrate(this, 500);
    tagSerial = GENFC.getTagId(getIntent());
}
```

It's works great. After this i read my id and parse it. I am using ndef-tools to parse the NDEF messages, but i think this is does not matter.

My problem is, when i am on the home screen, and my application is not running, when i first tap the NFC with the phone, my application is starting, but sadly, the onNewIntent method does not run.

I tried to search for it, i know, i am not the first who has this problem, and i read everywhere, i shoul add to this to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

No change.

Now, i also tried something else. I outsourced the whole thing from the onNewIntent into a handleIntent method, so my onNewIntent now seems like this:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent");
    // Set the intent
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);

}
```

And i am also calling the this handleIntent from the init method.
But the result are the same.

If i am calling this handlentent from the init like this:

```
handleIntent(getIntent());
```

For some reason, this condition will be false.

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
....
}
```

What do i wrong?

PS: my other problem is, i can not debug this whole thing, because if i am clicking the debug button in the eclipse, it's starts the application, so i can not simulate, what happens (with breakpoints), when the application starts because of the NFC tag starts it.

Ps2: now logged, what is the action when i start the application and it is:
Main activity(29861): Action is: android.intent.action.MAIN

**UPDATE**
After some researching, and playing with the settings, now i realized the following:
If i am using this in manifest:
    android:launchMode="singleTask"

and this filter:

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!--  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />  -->



            <data android:mimeType="application/hu.sma.htdalpha" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and data type is

```
*/*
```

, then everything is work fine, except, all TAG is opening my application, even if there are only a text like "adsdasd".

If i am using my own package, then apllications open, and action will be android.intent.action.MAIN again.

**UPDATE 2**
As Michael asked, i copy here the AndroidManifest.xml.
The description above is a littlebit confusing. The point of the problem, as i read about it, that something not ok with the intents. The package name is ok, but every time, every where onCreate, onNewIntent, onStart, onResume, everywhere if i Log.d the getIntent().getAction(), will be android.intent.action.MAIN, and android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED is never triggered. Only, if the application was started once.

The NDEF seems like this (see image)

[image: NDEF]

The manifest is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hu.sma.htdalpha"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="hu.sma.htdalpha.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <!-- 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/hu.sma.htdalpha" />
            </intent-filter>
             -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole intent filter from your manifest? Or better yet all intent filters that you registered in the manifest for that particular activity? Moreover could you confirm that you have the following NDEF message on your tag: `{ NFC Forum Text Record; Android Application Record }` or is it a different NDEF message?

Comment: Ok, now i am really confused. I removed the application record from the NDEF messages.
Now there is only 1 record, the text/plain record. In this case, now it works. Triggers the android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED in the onNewIntent. But now, if i have a tag with a text/plain record, every time launch my application. How can i earn that, to start my application only, if this is my tag, and if there is my id (check the NDEF above), and any other case ask, wich NFC program start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want your app to be started by your tag and want to receive the parsed NDEF message, your tag should contain the following:

1. An NDEF record that you want to filter upon **as the first record of the NDEF message** (you can only create intent-filters for the very first NDEF record on an NFC tag). In your case this would be the Text record. However, you might want to consider using an NFC Forum external type record with your custom application-specific type name instead (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#ext-type). The Text record should only be used if it contains human-readable non-interpreted *text*.
2. If you want to make sure that only your app is started with the tag **and** that your app's Play Store page is automatically opend if the user does not have the app installed, you can use an Android Application Record (AAR). This record should be the **last** record in the NDEF message. An AAR will be honored regardless of the position in the NDEF message.

Next, you have to create an appropriate intent filter for the activity that should receive the tag dicovery event and the NDEF message that triggered it:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Or if you used your custom NFC Forum external type:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
          android:host="ext"
          android:pathPrefix="/yourdomain.com:yourtypename"/>
</intent-filter>
```

If your app *does not have a matching intent filter* **and** your tag *contains an Android Application Record*, the first activity declared in your manifest that has an intent filter for `android.intent.action.MAIN` and with `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` will be started and as it does not declare to expect an NFC intent **it will be passed the `android.intent.action.MAIN`**. That's what happened in your case.

Next, in your activity, you can receive the NFC intent (with `getIntent()`) in `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, etc. and forward it to your `handleIntent(...)` method. As you filtered for NDEF_DISCOVERED, you will receive an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent. Thus you would use something like this:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to receive further NFC intents while your activity is already in the foreground, you can handle them in `onNewIntent()`. This method will only be called if you added the proper `launchMode` to your activity). Better yet you can register for the [foreground dispatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) to give your activity priority for receiving NFC events.

Finally, you should normally not use the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent in your manifest. This intent filter is meant as a fallback (if no other app's NFC intent filter matches) and to be backward compatible to the first edition of the NFC API (in Android 2.3). Moreover it is used for the catch-all version of the foreground dispatch.

Comment: You saved my life. Yesterday i cried, i know, it's a shame, but i stuck with this for 2 days. Now i know, AAR should be the last, i thought, it always be the first. I choosed the first method what you suggest me. So i am not using NFC Forym external type, but the text/plain. Second record in the NDEF is my AAR package name. Now everything is works as i expected. Really big thank you.